# Formula for the sum of distinct prime factors of $n$

Tags: prime-factorization

This seems like a simple question, but I have been searching the internet forever to find an answer. Is there a formula for the sum of the distinct prime factors of a given positive integer $n$?

Comment: If $f(n):=\sum_{p|n}p$ where $p$ is taken amongst the prime numbers, then $e^f$ is multiplicative, it can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a direct formula for the sum of distinct prime factors of n. 
If n is prime the answer is n itself. If n is composite and large, then first we have to find the prime decomposition of n, which is already difficult enough (for the number of primes less than an integer n see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function). If $n=\prod_{i}p_{i}^{a_{i}}$ then for the sum of distinct prime factors of n we can write $f(n)=\sum_{k}p_{{i}}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is closely related to the [Euler totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).